# How to find an operator's source code?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to call `bpy.ops.object.parent_clear` in blender background mode (no GUI) and it fails with an "context is incorrect" message. I would like to read the source code of the operator to better understand what is going on. I downloaded the source code of the blender 2.74 distribution. The error message indicates where the error occurs:

```
File ".../Resources/2.74/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in  __call__
ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.parent_clear.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

However, at that location one can only find

```
ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
```

which is another call. Where do I find the actual implementation of `parent_clear`?

Comment: You are right. For `parent_clear` it seems to be `ED_object_parent_clear`, which is performing the operation in the end. But for `duplicate_move_linked` for example?

Comment: you can see that `duplicate_move_linked` is just two calls on for `OBJECT_OT_duplicate` and one for `TRANSFORM_OT_translate` [see this page](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/object/object_ops.c$272)

Comment: tips on figurating out what to do about the `context is incorrect` error: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The naming scheme is `object.parent_clear` -> `OBJECT_OT_parent_clear`.

To find the source code you will usually find the declaration of the operator in the headerfile, somewhere in `source/blender/editors/*`, in this case it is [`source/blender/editors/object/object_intern.h`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/source/blender/editors/object/object_intern.h#l63)

The comment points to the source file [`source/blender/editors/object/object_relations.c`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/source/blender/editors/object/object_relations.c#l541)

```
 541 void OBJECT_OT_parent_clear(wmOperatorType *ot)
 542 {
 543         /* identifiers */
 544         ot->name = "Clear Parent";
 545         ot->description = "Clear the object's parenting";
 546         ot->idname = "OBJECT_OT_parent_clear";
 547 
 548         /* api callbacks */
 549         ot->invoke = WM_menu_invoke;
 550         ot->exec = parent_clear_exec;
 551 
 552         ot->poll = ED_operator_object_active_editable;
 553 
 554         /* flags */
 555         ot->flag = OPTYPE_REGISTER | OPTYPE_UNDO;
 556 
 557         ot->prop = RNA_def_enum(ot->srna, "type", prop_clear_parent_types, CLEAR_PARENT_ALL, "Type", "");
 558 }
```

The poll method checks for the right context. The exec method is located in the same file

```
 523 /* note, poll should check for editable scene */
 524 static int parent_clear_exec(bContext *C, wmOperator *op)
 525 {
 526         Main *bmain = CTX_data_main(C);
 527         const int type = RNA_enum_get(op->ptr, "type");
 528 
 529         CTX_DATA_BEGIN (C, Object *, ob, selected_editable_objects)
 530         {
 531                 ED_object_parent_clear(ob, type);
 532         }
 533         CTX_DATA_END;
 534 
 535         DAG_relations_tag_update(bmain);
 536         WM_event_add_notifier(C, NC_OBJECT | ND_TRANSFORM, NULL);
 537         WM_event_add_notifier(C, NC_OBJECT | ND_PARENT, NULL);
 538         return OPERATOR_FINISHED;
 539 }
```

I would recommend an IDE like QTCreator to follow the symbols though you might use grep/search the files manually.

Answer (score 1):

you can search in the source code available online on [this page](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/)
, also one of blender developers Campbell Barton has great videoes on searching and navigating the source code : [Tips on Searching/Navigating Blenders Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kniMTbcCko)  and  [Learning to Navigate Source & Simple Fix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ymoav0nNWQ)